# Flight from Lyon to Düsseldorf cancelled 15 minutes prior to departure. Am I eligible for compensation?

Tags: cancellations, compensation, delays, ec261

I had a confirmed ticket for a Eurowings flight from Lyon Saint-Exupery to Düsseldorf. I went to the airport well ahead of time, checked in, received my boarding pass, cleared security and was at the boarding gate well ahead of the stated cutoff time.

The flight was scheduled to depart from Lyon at 2030h. However, 15 minutes prior to departure, we were told that the flight had been cancelled due to technical reasons. I wasn't able to find out the exact nature of the issue. I wasn't advised of my rights, nor was I offered meal vouchers, or anything of the like. I was booked into a hotel for the night in the airport, the costs for this being borne by Eurowings. The hotel did not have anything that could be called a meal. They had some crisps and a bowl of fruits, far from what can be termed as a meal.

The next day I contacted Eurowings over phone to figure out a way to get back home. The alternative flights offered to me were either fully booked or extremely inconvenient to me. Thus, I travelled back to Düsseldorf at my own expense via train, and also incurred additional costs for coffee and lunch over the course of this journey. Am I eligible for reimbursement for these extra expenses (train tickets, lunch and coffee). Furthermore, can I file for compensation in addition to the aforementioned expenses? Does filing for reimbursement of additional expenses preclude any claim for compensation?

EDIT 1: Adding some explanations on what I mean by "**extremely inconvenient**". I am a non-EU national. The flights offered to me were via London, Istanbul and Munich. I was reluctant to fly out of the Schengen area because I wanted to avoid having to go through border control. The lines can get quite long in some places. Nonetheless, I agreed to travel via London. However, the Eurowings agent I spoke to on the phone told me she could not place me on that flight for reasons I don't know of. With Istanbul, it was the same reason, I wanted to avoid flying out of the Schengen area. Add to it a flying time of a little more than 3hours, and the fact that the flight to Istanbul was only one hour away when I was provided this option. I wasn't sure I would clear border control and security checks within this short span of time. Munich would have put me in Düsseldorf at 0600h the following day, with a night spent at the airport. The only direct flight was four days later, which would have affected my work.

EDIT 2: Adding some more information on why I decided to take a train I also asked for connections that would take me close to Düsseldorf, namely, Cologne, Berlin, and Frankfurt. Eurowings was unable to book me on flight to any of these destinations.

EDIT 3: I received the compensation for the delayed flight and the reimbursement for the mode of travel and the expenses incurred for coffee and lunch. Surprisingly, the claim was accepted within three weeks of my request.

Comment: Note that Eurowings, being the low-cost carrier of Lufthansa, is not necessarily forthcoming with compensations and such, even if you have a right to them. You may have to insist and threaten them with lawyers.

Comment: @Tom let me correct you. Note that Eurowings, being an airline, is not necessarily forthcoming with compensations and such, even if you have a right to them. You may have to insist and threaten them with lawyers.

Comment: Can you define "extremely inconvenient"? I would think that _I was expecting to be home before midnight on Saturday night, and lay about the house recovering on Sunday but the new flight didn't depart until 2330_ is quite different than, _I needed to be home Tuesday night so I could be at work Wednesday morning, but the new flight wouldn't have gotten me home until Wednesday afternoon_. Some of this difference may impact the options noted in the two answers provided so far.

Comment: @FreeMan I agree; if there's an objective need to be back by a certain time, that certainly strengthens your case.

Comment: @EarlGrey by my experience, the full-price airlines like Lufthansa are considerably more customer-friendly in this regard then the low-cost carriers. Might be a left-over from older times, or their understanding that the main reason they can charge higher prices is better customer service.

Comment: @Tom Not my experience at all. British Airways in particular are real ****holes, and will literally say "it was operational reasons...so extraordinary circumstances". And then, when it goes to CEDR/court, pull the COVID card out of the blue. The Danish NEB were retarded enough to buy it, whereas CEDR awarded me compensation

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can get reimbursement of ALL expenses, as well as EUR 250 in compensation. Hopefully you didn't consent to a refund of the original ticket, which could make getting the expenses back awkward.

Claim from Eurowings at https://www.eurowings.com/en/4u/online-service-for-the-right-to-compensation.html

If they deny any part of your claim claiming extraordinary circumstances, tell them you've already been informed it was due to technical issues, which aren't extraordinary circumstances. Tell them that if they don't confirm full payment within 7 days, you'll escalate further. You can do this at https://droits-passagers-aeriens.aviation-civile.gouv.fr/public/signalement?new-signalement=true

Comment: +1 for the links and details on how technical issues are handled but are you sure the OP can legitimately claim reimbursement for their train travel? I guess it could depend a bit on how inconvenient alternative flights really were but Eurowings did offer transportation to Düsseldorf.

Comment: True, I'm taking OP's word for it when they say "extremely inconvenient". But yes @pseudomonas, when was the first available flight? And how could they have offered fully booked flights? Doesn't quite add up, so can you please clarify

Comment: May also be helpful to know if when the OP phoned Eurowings, he/she informed the airline of the intention to arrange train travel

Comment: @Traveller That would certainly be an advantage; yet, if they failed to offer re-routing on the same or next day, they have next to no case IMO/IME

Comment: @Crazydre No, I did not agree to a refund of the original ticket. In fact, we were not informed about our rights at all. I think a bunch of us would have been left stranded in the airport close to midnight, since the situation after the flight was cancelled was chaotic and badly managed. It was only after a bunch of people, including me were getting increasingly anxious due the the lack of any updates, that we found someone who looked in-charge of the mess, and asked them to provide us overnight accommodation

Comment: @pseudomonas But you said you were offered alternative flights that were "extremely inconvenient". So when were those offered flights in relation to the cancelled one?

Comment: @Crazydre I was offered the alternatives the following day at 0900h. The flight to Istanbul was 1000h. The other two flights were in the afternoon. London did not work. And Munich was not appealing because I didn't want to spend another night in the airport.

Answer (score 21):

Under the relevant EU regulation, you are entitled to three separate things:

- Right to care: basically meals, hotel, and transportation to the hotel. Meal could have been better but the airline does not seem to have denied you this right. If you were forced to pay for your meal, you could ask Eurowings to reimburse you but if I am reading you correctly there simply wasn't any food to be had beyond crisps and fruit. One commenter also note that it was arguably past dinner time.
- Right to reimbursement or re-routing: Eurowings seems to have offered a solution but, importantly, you are always free to choose reimbursement or travel at a later date if the next available flight is not convenient for you.

  Obviously they should also inform you of this and since you chose to refuse the flight they offered, they should at least agree to reimburse your original Lyon-Düsseldorf ticket. Alternatively, if you push for them to pay your train ticket, you would forgo that reimbursement. It's up to you to decide what's easiest to claim or more advantageous.
- Compensation: For Lyon-Düsseldorf, you are entitled to €250 per person unless the carrier “can prove that the cancellation is caused by extraordinary circumstances which could not have been avoided even if all reasonable measures had been taken”. If compensation applies, it's completely separate from the right to care and the right to reimbursement or re-routing and should be paid within 7 days. So it should in principle already be paid while you are figuring out what to do with the other claims.

As far as the regulation is concerned, you don't generally have the right to choose any arbitrary way to go to your destination and the idea is that the airline, not the passengers, is in charge or organising it. Since you were offered transportation to Düsseldorf, I don't see how you could claim reimbursement for a completely different means of transportation and the meals resulting from that but there is a discussion in the comments about what counts as a suitable re-routing so it might still be worth trying.

Comment: I’m not sure I agree with you on not being able to claim reimbursement of the train trip. One is entitled to the first available re-routing, not necessarily on a flight from the same airline. I’m not sure this would preclude travel by train (airlines often reroute passengers on buses…). But of course, it would be either refund OR reimbursement of the alternative travel, not both.

Comment: @jcaron That's not what the regulation says, the airline is supposed to re-route you at the earliest opportunity and under comparable conditions. Now, if they leave you completely stranded, I believe you can indeed claim reimbursement instead but it's not a right to go and arrange any means of transportation by yourself or insist on the next available flight no matter what.

Comment: If I am reading the rules correctly the airline are expected to provide normal meals and then simple refreshments and snacks, for a flight scheduled at 2030h, what meal would be expected?

Comment: @Relaxed I've reclaimed for overland travel many times with zero fuss whenever the airline has failed to re-route me at a suitable time. It's always the compensation they get difficult about (fraudulently claiming extraordinry circumstances)

Comment: @JackAidley Had a couple of 2+ hour delays on Ryanair, and they've never fussed about reimbursing me for a GBP 11,18 Burger King meal

Comment: @JackAidley Dinner? But fair point, could it be someone assumed passengers would already have had a meal, although that would be more typical in Northern Europe than in France…

Comment: @Crazydre That's also what I would expect if they *fail* to re-route you but that's not how I read the question. Apart from the very subjective notion that the alternative was “extremely inconvenient”, all I see is the OP declining what they were offered. So again it all comes down to what is suitable or not… In the cases you have in mind, you just said you were not interested in the alternative they offered and hit them with a claim for your train ticket afterwards?

Comment: I don't see why the OP shouldn't try (unless they prefer to get their money back instead) but I still don't see how the regulation would *entitle* you to this no matter what.

Comment: The options Eurowings suggested were inconvenient because they offered to fly me back to Düsseldorf via Istanbul, London or via Munich. Opting for the latter would have put me in Düsseldorf at 0600h two days later. Istanbul was inconvenient because the flight to and from Istanbul takes a while, and I was worried about transit visa. I opted for London, but they were unable to place me on that flight, for reasons I don't know of. They did offer to fly me back direct to Düsseldorf on a flight four days later, which was not desirable.

Comment: @pseudomonas IMO you should've taken the Istanbul flight, as a transit visa is never required if staying in the transit area. Still, you should realistically be fine claiming back for the train if you point out that they were unable to put you on the London flight. Hopefully there won't be any factual dispute about their inability to reroute you via London, as that could turn out awkward

Comment: @Crazydre Yes, I found that out later. Even otherwise, I don't think I could have made the flight to Istanbul. The flight was at 1000h, and I was offered this at 0900h. I don't think I would have cleared security and border control within this window of time.

Comment: @pseudomonas Fair enough, that strengthens your case. Tell Eurowings 1) you were offered the Istanbul flight at 09:00 and didn't reasonably expect to be able to catch it at 10:00 due to queues (DON'T mention your misbelief about visas); 2) you accepted the London route but they were unable to book it without clear explanation; 3) thus, you rerouted yourself by train

Comment: @pseudomonas Also "I was reluctant to fly out of the Schengen area because I wanted to avoid having to go through border control" will NOT help you, so leave that out entirely. Only bring up the points in my comment above

Comment: @Relaxed If they offer re-routing on the same/next day, I usually accept it. The only exception is my wrongful denied boarding for easyJet LCA-LPL where I had an easyJet "connection" LPL-BFS. The next easyJet flight Cyprus-UK was at 15:00 the next day, but I had to be in BFS by 16:00, so me and an easyJet immigration support agent agreed she'd have the handling agent drive me LCA-PFO, I'd book a Ryanair flight PFO-EIN at 6:00, then train EIN-AMS, and she'd replace the LPL-BFS flight with AMS-BFS, then I'd email her team tickets PFO-AMS and they'd process instant compo+expenses